# Why is my VS-CODE unable to find a main method?

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

Guys why is VSCODE unable to find main method when it's already there ?

```
static void sayHello(String name) {
    System.out.println("Hello" + name);
}

public static void main(Strings[ ]args) {
    sayHello("David");
}
```

A screenshot
[image]

I also tried adding a class but.. Didn't work.

[second attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXlHH.png)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Java, but I'm pretty sure these are _methods_ and as such must be part of a `class` definition.  Maybe search around the internet for "Hello World" program examples in Java.  You'll see how they are different to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs following changes:

The revised code is as follows:

```
public class Myhello {  //Myhello is a class with first alphabet in capital
  static void sayHello() { //sayhello is method
    System.out.println("hello!");
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    sayHello();
  }
}
```

Comment: still didn't work. I mean it's not about the code. Even a little hello world doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with java is that you want every thing to be inside a class. and, remember this important bit - "the class name should match the file name." so, that is probably the issue. i.e. - in 1, code isn't inside any class. in second, the class name doesn't match the file name. if you are new to java, I suggest going through [w3's java tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/java/default.asp) this is a text based tutorial so, you can keep your own pace or even speed run through it [do try out every thing they teach by yourself too]. I seriously recommend it since I started there and almost finished it within 1-2 weeks without any help.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. I'll match the class name with the file name

Comment: Doesn't work. I think i need to re-install VS-CODE.

Comment: try using intellij. I have had problems with getting java to run on VsCode. So, I tried intellij instead. It worked for me. So, I didnt really bother with vscode to try and fix/find the issue. Also, make sure your java install is done properly. you can find a tutorial for that on youtube easily.

Comment: okay then i'll try intellij. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

S in String in `public static void main(String[] args) {` Should be in Uppercase.[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMwuB.jpg)

Comment: I did i, Still it cannot find "main method"

Answer (score 0):

1. Your java file's name doesn't match the class name. Please rename your .java file as `hello.java`.
2. Pay attention to the args in main method should be `String[]`, while it's `Strings[]` in your screenshot.
3. The white dot after your .java file means your file wasn't saved. Save it before running.

`hello.java:`

```
public class hello{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Please correct the above things, after `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` from command Palette the run again.

Comment: can you please explain how i can Clean Java Language Server Workspace

Comment: @ElevenBits. Open Command Palette and search this command